# I need to get a single variable equation from this expression.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need some help of you guys solving the following equation:

\begin{equation}
I_{D}(t)=k\cdot (1-\frac{h-\frac{1}{c}\int{dt \cdot I_{D}(t)}}{p})
\end{equation}

where $k$, $h$, $c$ and $p$ are constants and I want to get $I_{D}(t)$

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "find $I_D(t)$?  What you have now is an "integral equation".  What techniques do you know for solving them?  It is not difficult to convert it to a differential equation:  Multiply both sides by p and divide by k to get $\frac{p}{k}I_D(t)= p- h- \frac{1}{c}\int I_D(t) dt$.  Now subtract p- h from both sides and multiply by c to get $cI_D(t)+ c(h- p)= \int I_D(t) dt$.  Finally differentiate both sides to get the differential equation $c\frac{dI_D(t)}{dt}= I_D(t)$.  That should be easy to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiate both sides of the equation:

$$ I_D'(t) = \dfrac{k}{cp} I_D(t)$$

which is a differential equation you should know how to solve.